# Can Golang use a string to perform an operation?

Tags: go

I want to create a method which conditionally performs an operation on two ints. In essence, it should do the following

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    op := "*"
    a := 100
    b := 200

    fmt.Println(a op b)
}
```

Is this possible in Golang without using a switch statement? The only way that I've been able to do this is:

```
switch a {
case "+":
    fmt.Println(a + b)
case "*":
    fmt.Println(a * b)
case "/":
    fmt.Println(a / b)
case "-":
    fmt.Println(a - b)
}
```

I want to make this more scalable for operations like `<`, `<=`, `<<`, etc.

Comment: Go is a compiled language. Operations must be known at compile time.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this post got downvotes...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string cannot be used to perform an operation.

A switch statement is a good way to solve the problem. Another option is to use a map:

```
var funcs = map[string]func(int, int) int{
    "+": func(a, b int) int { return a + b },
    "-": func(a, b int) int { return a - b },
    "*": func(a, b int) int { return a * b },
    "/": func(a, b int) int { return a / b },
}

fmt.Println(funcs["-"](6, 4))
fmt.Println(funcs["+"](6, 4))
fmt.Println(funcs["*"](6, 4))
```